# Table Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have coded a table but for some reason, the right column is not aligning with the left column.

The left column is being placed slightly down. Here is a fiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/5Me4L/

Code:

```
<table width='620'>
    <tr>
        <td width='310'>
            <span style='font-size:21px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#00abbd; font-weight:bold'>Pay Monthly</span>
            <table width='310' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='border-color:#00abbd; border-width:0px; border-style:solid; padding:3px'>
                <tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td width='160'><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Call to Argentina</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 3.88 /min</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Call to Malta</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 3.40/min</p></td></tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Call to Zone 4 </strong> </p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 3.88 /min</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Calling other Zones</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 4.00 /min</p></td></tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Receiving Calls</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 1.46 /min</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Data</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'> &euro; 17.48</p>
                    </td></tr>
                <tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>SMS</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 0.39</p></td></tr>
                <tr><td><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>MMS</strong></p></td>
                    <td><p class='rates'>&euro; 0.22 + €17.48</p></p></td></tr>
            </table> 
            <td width='310'>
                <span style='font-size:21px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#00abbd; font-weight:bold'>Pay Monthly</span>
                <table width='310' cellpadding='6' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='border-color:#00abbd; border-width:0px; border-style:solid; padding:3px'>
                    <tr bgcolor='#eeeeee'><td width='160'><p class='rates' style='color:#00abbd;'><strong>Call to Argentina</strong></p></td><td><p class='rates'>&euro; 3.88 /min</p></td></tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it should look:

[image]

Comment: **Why do you have a table in a table?** Isn't this just a two column table?

Comment: @Paulie_D I did that So I can easily place the rows in in the inner table

Comment: but in the fiddle the **right** column is placed slightly down. is that you problem?

Comment: Is it my imagination or did the image and code just disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align:top` property to your `tr`:

```
tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/5Me4L/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use vertical align on your table cell, like so:

```
<td width='310' valign="top">
```

Comment: valign is not supported in HTML5 according to the documentation. CSS is definitely the way to go

Comment: `valign` is best to have for legacy support/if you're doing a HTML email. But definitely have `vertical-align: top` as well to futureproof it.

Answer (score 0):

On your second  I modified it to . That will force that table data to the top. There are better ways to code table though. You may check out his page - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

**Add a vertical-align:top property to your td**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9UZa6/1/)**

**CSS**

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```